# How in Unity2D to stop the animation using a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity2d, most of mechanics are implemented. What remains is only a menu pop up after death. I have created the menu, I just need to make it appear upon death

I need the collision with the enemy character animation, background and movements of enemies. I have no idea how to do this.

I want all the animations to stop, the game to be put on pause, and menu a with two buttons to appear : restart and quit the game.

Player Script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class HeroJumpScript : MonoBehaviour

{ 
    //Player Script
    private Animator anim;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    private bool isDeath = false; 
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public Transform EnemyCheck;
    private float groundRadius = 1.0f;
    private float enemyRadius = 4.0f;
    public LayerMask WhatIsGround;
    public Text ScoreText;
    public float score = 0f;
    public float verticalImpuls;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public bool IsRuning { get; set; }

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, WhatIsGround);
        isDeath = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(EnemyCheck.position, enemyRadius, WhatIsGround);

        anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
        anim.SetBool("Enemy", isDeath);
        anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", rb.velocity.y);

        if (!isGrounded)
            return;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpuls), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void OnCrash()
    {

    }
    //reading score
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
    //jump
    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 30));
        }
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
    //implementation of the collision with the enemy and the ground conditional death
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {

        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {

        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collis)
    {
        if (collis.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

enemy move script:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float speed = 4f;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Vector2 vel = rb.velocity;
        vel.x = -1 * speed;
        rb.velocity = vel;
    }
}
```

P.s.The whole text was translated in google translator

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. What are you trying to do? Do you want a menu to appear on death?

Comment: That would be all the animation stayed in the game on pause was put, and a menu with two buttons: restart and quit the game.

Comment: So.... You want a menu to appear when a player dies. This menu has 2 options correct?

Comment: Menu I have done, I need to figure out how to make the menu appear after a collision with an obstacle.

Comment: Now that makes sense. I will edit your question for you in hopes someone with more knowledge can help but I'll also try and point you in the right direction

Comment: to pause the game you can use time.timescale = 0 and for load menu you make s canvas appear using setActive call on gameobject

Comment: Anil, thanks you so help me.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to look at this method here:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
 if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {

} 
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {

} 
}
```

On the second if statement you are checking if you have collided with an enemy. Here is where you want to program your death functionality assuming you want the player to die when they touch an enemy.

Comment: I think I just need to add the function of playing the animation menu appears.

Comment: Sadly my knowledge of unity is limited. You will likely have to wait for someone else to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bool that turns true on collision and then with that bool you can stop the animations and pop up a menu so:

```
private bool death = false;
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collis)
{ 
   death = true
}
```

And now when death is true you can add whatever you want for example

```
if (death == true)
{
    anim.SetBool("DyingAnim", true)
}
```